# Finding the Coordinates (2D Array) of Lowest Value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I feel like I'm missing something terribly obvious, but I cannot seem to find the array pair with the lowest value.

I have an `int[,] worldMapXY` where a 2D map is stored, say `worldMapXY[0,0]` through `worldMapXY[120,120]`.  All values of map's array are 1 (wall\invalid) or 0 (path/valid).

I'm writing a method that will find coordinates in one of the eight cardinal directions to create a spawn point.  So I also have `int[,] validSpotArr` which has a subset of bounds of the map closest to the direction I'm setting the spawn.  The values for wall/invalid locations are set to `9999`, the values for path/valid locations are set to `(x + y)`.  This is all specific to the bottom left corner, nearest to `[0,0]`, hence "BL" or "Bottom Left"

```
        case "BL":

        for (int x = (int)border + 1; x < worldX + (int)border / 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = (int)border + 1; y < worldY + (int)border / 4; y++) 
            {
                if (worldMapXY[x,y] = 0)
                {
                    validSpotArr[x,y] = x + y;
                }

                else
                {
                    validSpotArr[x,y] = 9999;
                }
            }
        }
```

What I can't quite wrap my head around is how to determine the coordinates/index of `validSpotArr` with the lowest value in such a way that I could pass those as separate x and y coordinates to another function (to set the spawn point).  I suspect there's a lambda operator that may help, but I literally don't understand lambdas.  Clearly that needs to be my next point of study.

E.g. - if `validSpotArr[23, 45] = 68`, and 68 is the lowest value, how do I set x=23 and y=45?

Edit:  I tried messing around with something like this, but it isn't right:

```
    Array.IndexOf(validSpotArr, validSpotArr.Min());
```

Comment: This is a train wreck. :) Just FTR (i) Why do you want the "lowest value", Jesse? For what reason?  Did you realize that 8,9 and 9,8 have...the same "value"? (ii) each point on your grid should be a small Class (or at least a struct) that has more information contained in it - just pass 'em around (iiii) what is the porblem passing 23,45 to a function? `private void test(int x,int y);` Not that it matters but (iv) why are you dividing by 4 at some point? (v) I can't see lambda functions being relevant in any way here, at all, I don't think. (vi) just for clarity are you spawning the walls or??

Comment: Not a train wreck at all - it's quite functional and relatively speedy.  No, I'm not making Minecraft.  Yes, I realize that [8,9] and [9,8] have the same value - and that's not a problem, frankly, though Aleksei's solution below makes more sense in the long run because in the other directions (say Top-Left or Top-Right) the values need to be evaluated differently.  The division by four is to limit the set.  For the bottom left corner, I don't want to evaluate every cell on the map, I want to evaluate only the cells in that quadrant.

Comment: Each cell IS a class, but that isn't relevant to assigning it's values to another object entirely.  I need a world location, and world units are mapped to the int[,] indices.  On the map load, after all cellular automata and smoothing have occurred, the entire map is repositioned so that the map's (0,0) is the world's (0,0). This allows easy placement of objects via coordinates.  And yes, there are walls, but it's strictly a barrier as this is entirely 2D.  All vertices and triangles are calculated based on where 0s and 1s meet, and walls are created as colliders.

Comment: Passing the class for the cell around has zero benefit.  While each cell is aware of it's surrounding cells, they aren't necessarily aware of their overall location in the world.  Iterating over the array is much quicker and makes far more sense.  Why would I pass cell class objects around until they determine which is closest to a particular index/coordinate?  That would be expensive and wouldn't really be a very smart way to go.

Comment: I'm actually more confused by your comments than anything.  Why would I pass ALL of the values?  In a 256x256 map, that's 65,536, and since I have a border it really becomes 296x296 (87,616).  If I know I want one quadrant and I know that there's always open cells in the outer edge of each quadrant, I can remove all my border space (which is useless) and use a fourth or each direction (so an eighth of the mapspace) and only run calculations on a 64 x 64 section, for a total of 4,096 cells - less than 5% of the total array space.

Comment: I apologize - I can't tell if you're being rude or not.  I assumed so, but perhaps that isn't the case.  At any rate, thanks for stopping by.

Comment: Well i didn't mean to sound pompous I'm very self-effacing, but I'm struggling to see what's going on.  Sorry.  Regarding 65,536 I wasn't referring (ii) to passing them "all around", i just mean you'd pass around little structs - you appear to be asking how to pass around "two values at once" right?

Comment: like you'd have a little struct 3,5,71.87, and you'd look over a list of a hundred of those (or whatever) and the smallest "71.87" might be "13.52" .. then you'd have the first two values as well. I'm also completely mystified by Aleksei's answer, so, ... no worries :-)  Cheers!

Comment: I apologize - it seems that I speak Martian half the time around here.  Of course I know what I mean, so it's difficult sometimes to see why others do not.  I'm not asking how to pass two values around - that can be done countless ways.  I think what I was trying to get to, at the very bottom of everything, was how to pass the index value of an int[,] array such that int[54, 76] would be broken down so that x=54 and y=76.  I can get the value of the array, I don't know how to get the values of the index itself with a 2D array.  Array.IndexOf doesn't work on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: in the Unity milieu, just return a Vector2 from the function

Comment: it's possible you just want to flatten the array, as Alek says.  In other words, simply return x * width + y. it's that simple.  (it seems a chore though when you can just return a Vector2  :O )  Cheers for now!

Comment: I am passing a Vector2 (well, actually a Vector3 with z=0, and there's a reason for that).  But I have to get x and y values, which are the first and second indices from the array.  Hence I need to get those index values.  If validSpotArr[45, 54] contians the value I want, I need to pass back Vector3(45, 54, 0).

Comment: I really just think you need a conventional "MVC" approach.  But anyways, good luck alright!  You rock!

Comment: @JoeBlow you may be right (I may be crazy?) but this is a proof of concept piece and I'm new(ish) to C#. My background is in C and perl and mostly from the perspective of a QA Engineer rather than a programmer. I can break software and fix code, but writing code from the ground up is something I haven't done since the 90s lol.

Comment: Well the main point is to enjoy yourself then, you don't have people's life in your hands, you're not developing for aircraft control or truss analysis. Enjoy!

Comment: @JesseWilliams Posted a toolset I use sometimes when having to work with N-dimensional arrays: [Camila.ArrayUtils](https://github.com/AOmelaienko/Camila.ArrayUtils/). Maybe you'd find them useful (although they'd require some work to be useful in Unity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not precisely an answer to your question, in a strictly given situation I'd probably go for finding those from within the cycles, i.e.

```
int minValidSpot = int.MaxValue, minX, minY;
for (int x = (int)border + 1; x < worldX + int(border) / 4; x++)
    {
        for (int y = (int)border + 1; y < worldY + int(border) / 4; y++) 
        {
            if (worldMapXY[x,y] = 0)
            {
                validSpotArr[x,y] = x + y;
            }
            else
            {
                validSpotArr[x,y] = 9999;
            }
            if ( minValidSpot > validSpotArr[x,y] )
            {
                minValidSpot = validSpotArr[x,y];
                minX = x;
                minY = y;
            }
        }
    }
```

Other than that, if looking for some kind of more universal solution, I'd probably just flatten that array, the maths for index conversion (nD<=>1D) are pretty simple.

Comment: Hmmm, that would definitely do the trick.  It would be nice to evaluate outside of the loop, but I'll give this a shot and see how long it takes.  Might not be awful so long as the map size isn't too large.

Comment: Actually, yes - that's great. I apparently need coffee - this isn't going to hurt performance since it's already looping through all the values anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: Haha, it was a long night when I asked this.  Aside from my initial misstep, I also realized that there would be at least four possible "sets" of requirements depending on the ordinal or cardinal directions being looked at - two each for x and for y.  All is well now and the method is working.  :)